# Matrix norm inequality Frobenius and l1: $\|A\|_1\le \sqrt{rank(A)}\|A\|_F$ and $\|uu'-vv'\|_1\le\sqrt{2}\|uu'-vv'\|_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Is it true that $\|A\|_1\le \sqrt{rank(A)}\|A\|_F$?

I met a derivation says: $\|uu'-vv'\|_1\le\sqrt{2}\|uu'-vv'\|_F$, where $u,v$ are unit vectors and $u'$ is transpose. I can't derive this claim.

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably help if you add at least the source where you saw this proof. (Or even copied the whole proof it is not two long.)

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak ! It is http://www-math.mit.edu/~rigollet/PDFs/RigNotes15.pdf . On page 96, last equation of (4.8) in the proof of Davis-Kahan $sin(\theta)$ theorem.

Comment: I think that information is important enough to be included into the question. BTW you may notice that the authors say: "we used the fact that the matrix $uu'-vv'$ has rank at most $2$".

Answer (score 1):

No.

Let $A = \left[1,1,1,1\right]^T$. Then $\|A|_1 = 4$, $\|A\|_F = 2$, and $rank(A) = 1$. For this matrix $\|A\|_1 > \sqrt{rank(A)}\|A\|_F$

However for any $m\times n$ matrix $A$:
$$\|A\|_1 \leq \sqrt{m}\|A\|_F$$

Comment: Thanks! In proving $||uu'-vv'||_1\le\sqrt{2}||uu'-vv'||_F$, the author gives the hint that he uses the fact matrix $uu'-vv'$ has rank at most 2. Is it enough to prove this? I can't get it.

Comment: Well, inequality $||uu'-vv'||_1\le\sqrt{2}||uu'-vv'||_F$ is also false for general $u$, $v$, unless $u$, $v$ are two dimensional vectors.